# Warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type (Pointers and structures)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have below two structures defined for my maze robot.

```
struct mazecells{
    char type;
    int reachable;
    int visited;
};

typedef struct maze {
    struct mazecells **M;
    int startx, starty;
    int numrows, numcolumns;
    int initdir;
}maze_t;

void ReadMaze(maze_t *maze) {
    char **mazeValue;

... remaining declaration and logic ...
```

Inside `mazevalue` I have read the maze input and then I am trying to assign it to you `struct maze_t` using `maze->M = mazeValue`. I'm getting below warning:

```
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
     maze->M = mazeValue;
```

Am I misunderstanding or missing something?

Comment: type of `M` is `struct mazecells **`, not `char **`.

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491704/is-it-possible-to-cast-a-char-to-a-struct)?

Comment: `mazeValue` has type `char **`; you're assigning it to a variable of type `struct mazecells **`.

Comment: mazevalue is char** while M is struct mazecells ** type. You should explicitly cast the char** to mazecells** . That will remove the warning. But first check are you sure about what you are doing. do you really want to cast mazeValue to struct mazecells or you really are missing something.

Comment: @Ramandeep Punia  - how to do it?

Comment: How do you read the maze? Could you continue the code?

Comment: @user6344678 simply cast it. maze->M = (struct mazecells **)mazevalue; But i don't think you really want to do that. It is not a good idea to cast from one type to another like this unless you are talking about void pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`mazeValue` is of type `char **` (i.e. pointer to pointer to char) while `maze->M` is of type `struct mazecells **` (i.e. pointer to pointer to struct mazecells).

The warning states that these two variables are of different types of pointers, and you are assigning one to the other, which could lead to unexpected results.

Depending on how you read the values, you might want to change the type of `mazeValue`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing it but why don't you make `mazeValue` a `mazecells`?

```
struct mazecells{
    char type;
    int reachable;
    int visited;
};

typedef struct maze {
    struct mazecells **M;
    int startx, starty;
    int numrows, numcolumns;
    int initdir;
}maze_t;

void ReadMaze(maze_t *maze) {
    struct mazecells **mazeValue;

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these two lines:

```
 struct mazecells **M;
 char **mazeValue;
```

As you can clearly see, these two variables have different types, and because of that, you're getting **warning**: *assignment from incompatible pointer type* when you're trying to assing this value `maze->M = mazeValue;`

Answer (score 0):

Types must match each other. The following is a clean compile without warnings that hopefully has something you can use.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct mazecells {
    char type;
    int reachable;
    int visited;
};

typedef struct maze {
    struct mazecells **M;
    int startx, starty;
    int numrows, numcolumns;
    int initdir;
} maze_t;


int main() {
    maze_t maze1 = { .startx = 1, .starty = 1 };
    struct mazecells mz = { .type = 'A', .reachable = 1, .visited = 1 };
    struct mazecells * mptr = &mz;
    struct mazecells ** mptr2 = &mptr;
    maze1.M = mptr2;
    struct mazecells * structmazecells = * maze1.M;
    printf("%d", structmazecells->visited);
    return 0;
}
```